# I have morris graph in my project i want show orders in morris graph dynamically by using mysql data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, morris.js

i have moris graph in project  html code below.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="chart">
    <div class="chart-tittle"> <span>Listings &amp; Orders Timeline by Month</span> </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="morris">
        <div id="hero-area" class="graph"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jquery code

```
 var Script = function () {
      $(function () {
          Morris.Area( {
              element: 'hero-area', data: [ {
                  period: "2016-01", order: 647, listing: 700
              }
              ,
              {
                  period: "2016-02", order: 247, listing: 500
              }
              ,
              {
                  period: "2016-03", order: 347, listing: 790
              }
              ,
              {
                  period: "2016-04", order: 467, listing: 800
              }
              ,
              {
                  period: "2016-05", order: 1047, listing: 2000
              }
              ],
              xkey: 'period',
              ykeys: ['order',
              'listing'],
              labels: ['ORDER',
              'LISTING'],
              hideHover: 'auto',
              lineWidth: 1,
              pointSize: 5,
              lineColors: ['#4a8bc2',
              '#ff6c60',
              '#a9d86e'],
              fillOpacity: 0.5,
              smooth: true
          }
          );
      }
      );
  }
  ();
```

i set static data in jquery i want all dynamically so how the set data dynamically in jquery. i want to show my orders and listing in morris table and also five month data.

Comment: you are missing a  "="

Comment: please tell me any how to resolve above problem

Comment: use ajax to retrieve the dynamic data

Comment: ok  i will try using ajax